# match a string not after another string

Tags: javascript, regex

This

```
var re = /[^<a]b/; 
var str = "<a>b";

console.log(str.match(re)[0]);
```

matches `>b`.

However, I don't understand why this pattern `/[^<a>]b/` doesn't match anything. I want to capture only the "b".

Comment: `[^<a>]b` would try to match 1 character that is not <, a, or > and then a b character, since <,a,> are all before b there is nothing to match. if the string you tried to match was say '<a>kb` then you would get a match.

Comment: Just a reminder: don't expect to manage to parse HTML code with regexps. It has been tried more than once, and it does not work in any practical acceptation of the word.
You will manage to tweak a few isolated patterns, but as soon as you will want to match opening and closing tags or embedded elements, it will fail.

Comment: @kuroineko I know. It's just part of the regex101 quiz I am doing for fun.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `/[^<a>]b/` doesn't do anything is that you are ignoring `<`, `a`, and `>` as *individual characters*, so rewriting it as `/[^><a]b/` would do the same thing. I doubt this is what you want, though. Try the following:

```
var re = /<a>(b)/; 
var str = "<a>b";

console.log(str.match(re)[1]);
```

This regex looks for a string that looks like `<a>b` first, but it captures the `b` with the parentheses. To access the `b`, simply use `[1]` when you call `.match` instead of `[0]`, which would return the entire string (`<a>b`).

Comment: okay thank you. But I don't want to use a capture like this though. I want to understand how to match it using the negation character.

Comment: @thomas You don't use the negation character to match `<a>`. Using brackets says that you want a character in your original string that **is not** the character(s) in the brackets. That's not what you're looking for, though. What you're thinking of is probably a negative lookahead, like @joeytje50 says in their answer.

Comment: @thomas Think of it this way `[^<a>]` means "don't match it if it contains any of those characters, even if they are individual and regardless of order" then `b` means to match the "b". So you're asking it to find "b" when it isn't preceded by those characters. What you really want is to find "b" when it is preceded by those characters, but exclude them.

Comment: so why can't I do something like `[^(<a>)]b`?

Comment: That says "I want a character that's not `<a>`, then a `b`." So that would match `ab`, `&b`, `9b`, etc., but *not* `<a>b`, as you want.

Answer (score 2):

What you're using here is a match for a `b` preceded by any character that is not listed in the group. The syntax `[^a-z+-]` where the `a-z+-` is a range of characters (in this case, the range of the lowercase Latin letters, a plus sign and a minus sign). So, what your regex pattern matches is any `b` preceded by a character that is NOT `<` or `a`. Since `>` doesn't fall in that range, it matches it.

The range selector basically works the same as a list of characters that are seperated by OR pipes: `[abcd]` matches the same as `(a|b|c|d)`. Range selectors just have an extra functionality of also matching that same string via `[a-d]`, using a dash in between character ranges. Putting a `^` at the start of a range automatically turns this positive range selector into a negative one, so it will match anything BUT the characters in that range.

What you are looking for is a negative lookahead. Those can exclude something from matching longer strings. Those work in this format: `(?!do not match)` where `do not match` uses the normal regex syntax. In this case, you want to test if the preceding string does not match `<a>`, so just use:

```
(?!<a>)(.{3}|^.{0,2})b
```

That will match the `b` when it is either preceded by three characters that are not `<a>`, or by fewer characters that are at the start of the line.

PS: what you are probably looking for is the "negative lookbehind", which sadly isn't available in JavaScript regular expressions. The way that would work is `(?<!<a>)b` in other languages. Because JavaScript doesn't have negative lookbehinds, you'll have to use this alternative regex.

Answer (score 0):

you could write a pattern to match anchor tag and then replace it with empty string

```
var str = "<a>b</a>";    
str = str.replace(/((<a[\w\s=\[\]\'\"\-]*>)|</a>)/gi,'')
```

this will replace the following strings with 'b'

```
<a>b</a>
<a class='link-l3'>b</a>
```

to better get familiar with regEx patterns you may find this website very useful [regExPal](http://regexpal.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Your code :

```
var re = /[^<a>]b/; 
var str = "<a>b";
console.log(str.match(re));
```

Why `[^<a>]b` is not matching with anything ?

The meaning of `[^<a>]b` is any character except `<` or `a` or  `>` then `b` .

Hear `b` is followed by `>` , so it will not match .

If you want to match `b` , then you need to give like this :

```
var re = /(?:[\<a\>])(b)/; 
var str = "<a>b";    
console.log(str.match(re)[1]);
```

**[DEMO And EXPLANATION](http://regex101.com/r/lW0fS5)**

Comment: Why are you escaping `<` and `>`?

Comment: @M42 : [>] means  a single character in the list &gt;

Comment: I don't understand, why have you replaced the back slashes by forward slashes? You have now to escape the forward slashes.